# The best way to create an IP whitelist with nginx

Tags: ip, nginx

we want to give access to an update server to only certain IPs and use [this nginx config](https://github.com/Freifunk-Nord/nord-bat15-transfer/blob/master/go) so far:

```
allow 2a03:2267:4e6f:7264:f6f2:6dff:fe49:e4a2;
allow 2a03:2267:4e6f:7264:a2f3:c1ff:fe7a:4bc6;
...
deny all;
```

But it seems that nginx has a limit of allow rules at around 250.

How can we increase this limit, so we can configure a larger whitelist here. Or is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `map` to achieve the same effect. For example:

```
map $remote_addr $deny {
    default 1;
    2a03:2267:4e6f:7264:f6f2:6dff:fe49:e4a2 0;
    2a03:2267:4e6f:7264:a2f3:c1ff:fe7a:4bc6 0;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($deny) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details and [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) in the use of `if`.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a whitelist based on global server access you might be better served using iptables for this.

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -s 2a03:2267:4e6f:7264:f6f2:6dff:fe49:e4a2 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -s 2a03:2267:4e6f:7264:a2f3:c1ff:fe7a:4bc6 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

Make sure you block IPv4 also if it is enabled.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```